# How can I convert an eclipse-dependent application into an eclipse-independent application?

Tags: java, eclipse

I developed an application in eclipse that uses many of the classes of the eclipse framework and requires eclipse to run. But now I'm being required to decouple it from eclipse and make it a standalone application. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please tell me which platform are you working on and what Eclipse library did you use in your application?

Comment: I am using eclipses's core, jdt, jface, swt, ui etc libraries. and what do you mean by platform?

Comment: by platform I mean whether you are using Eclipse for Java application, or any plugins to code in C++, Python, Ruby, Scala etc..

Comment: @shankar, sorry, its for java application.

Answer (score 3):

You might have luck using **File / Export... / Java / Runnable Jar File**. This will create a standalone .jar file that should be possible to run without Eclipse. You may however need to experiment with the various settings to get it to behave exactly how you want depending on what libraries you are using.

In general however, I'd suggest using a proper build/dependency management tool such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). This will take a bit of time to learn at first, but my experience is that it will make you more productive in the long run....

Comment: exporting as a jar is good idea, but how to resolve the dependencies during the runtime of the application.

Comment: the export has an option to package the needed libraries.... generally works for me

Answer (score 0):

Start by commenting out the imports for the offending libraries. This will turn red any references to those libraries in your code.  Then substitute a different library or refactor your code.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "decouple" it from eclipse? Do you mean you can no longer rely on any of the eclipse libraries, or that you simply don't want it running as a module in the IDE?

If it's the former, you have a lot of rewriting to do.

If it's the latter, then you'll want to basically bundle your module with an "empty" eclipse framework application. This doesn't "unbundle" eclipse, eclipse is still there, but now you don't have any of the IDE modules etc, and instead you have a stand alone ECLIPSE BASED application.

Comment: I dont want it running as a module in the IDE, instead I want to run it in command prompt with normal java command.

Comment: Right. Essentially, an Eclipse program is a modular program built on a skeleton. Normally, your skeleton is the IDE. You need to start with an empty one, and add your module to that. Then you'll have a stand alone Eclipse app. I can't speak to the mechanics of this, however.

Answer (score 0):

Create a standalone jar file from the Eclipse project as mentioned by Mikera, or you need to re-factor the code such that it doesn't depend on Eclipse libraries.

There is no point in creating a Java application which depends on certain IDEs or platforms. Java code should be independent (which is why it has the power to run on any platform which has JVM installed in it.

Try removing the dependency from your project to the Eclipse libraries. See if you can simulate the same thing using Standard Java libraries. If not, try to create a JAR for your project from Eclipse. If nothing works out, try looking for some 3rd party APIs.